# ParentedTree: Expected a node value and child list or a single string or 'ParentedTree' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

Each `ParentedTree` may have at most one parent.  In particular, subtrees may not be shared. Any attempt to reuse a single `ParentedTree` as a child of more than one parent (or as multiple children of the same parent) will cause a `ValueError` exception to be raised.

There is a requirement of not sharing my subtrees in my corpus and hence I am using ParentedTree. Why I am getting this error? What should I do?

```
tree=ParentedTree(tree.pprint());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fromstring` method like this

```
tree2 = nltk.Tree.fromstring(tree1.pprint())
```